# How to pattern match incoming data stream?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, stream, pattern-matching

I am currently working on a project which requires me to Tap in the data from GPIB bus serial communication channel and dump the output file into one folder. Please find the code below ,

```
import os.path
import serial
import sys
from time import sleep

comport = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser = serial.Serial()

try:
    ser = serial.Serial( comport, 9600, timeout=0.5 )

    # Switch to DEVICE mode
      cmd = '++mode 0'
      print('Sending:', cmd)
      cmd = cmd + '\n'
      ser.write(cmd.encode('UTF-8'))
      s = ser.read(256);
      if len(s) > 0:
      print(s)

    # Set instrument to LISTEN ONLY mode
      cmd = '++lon 1'
      print('Sending:', cmd)
      cmd = cmd + '\n'
      ser.write(cmd.encode('UTF-8'))

      while True:
         s = ser.read(256);
         if len(s) > 0:
         print(s)

  except(serial.SerialException, e):
  print(e)
  f.close()

  except(KeyboardInterrupt, e):
  ser.close()
  f.close()
```

I haven't tested the code , but it should probably work. Setting the GPIB Adaptor to ++lon mode make it to just listen to all communication done via GPIB bus.

I would be seeing a stream of data when the code is executed. I would like to write every line of stream into a file until the following match is found "**U\r\n**" , This represent the end of 1 stream and the command following this should be written to next file and so on.

The line containing "**U\r\n**" should also be last line written into the output file.

Comment: What is the problem you face?

Comment: @Scandrett , I would like to know how can i search the "s" for pattern matching "U\r\n" and then write the content till then into an output file instead of printing out to console.